# Start Python Celery task via Redis Pub/Sub

Tags: python, redis, celery

Is there an efficient way to start tasks via Redis Pub/Sub and return 
the value of the task back to a Pub/Sub channel to start another task 
based on the result?

Does anybody have an idea on how to put this together? Maybe 
decorators are a good idea to handle and prepare the return value back 
to a Pub/Sub channel without changing the code of the task too much.

Any help is very much appreciated!

Comment: +1, very interesting question. i'd love to hear more about the backgrounds

Answer (score 1):

The problem with using pub/sub is that it's not persistant.  If you're looking to do closer to real time communication celery might not be your best choice.